# Decrease thickness of svg path

Tags: html, svg

Is there any way to decrease svg path thickness? I have following icon in svg format but this icon is made by single path. Adjusting atrributes "fill" or "stroke-width" not working.

What I am trying to do is reduce thickness of visible border by half.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <g>
        <path d="M24,14.059V5.584L18.414,0H0v32h24v-0.059c4.499-0.5,7.998-4.309,8-8.941C31.998,18.366,28.499,14.556,24,14.059z    M17.998,2.413L21.586,6h-3.588V2.413z M2,30V1.998h14v6.001h6v6.06c-1.752,0.194-3.352,0.89-4.652,1.941H4v2h11.517   c-0.412,0.616-0.743,1.289-0.994,2H4v2h10.059C14.022,22.329,14,22.661,14,23c0,2.829,1.308,5.351,3.349,7H2z M23,29.883   c-3.801-0.009-6.876-3.084-6.885-6.883c0.009-3.801,3.084-6.876,6.885-6.885c3.799,0.009,6.874,3.084,6.883,6.885   C29.874,26.799,26.799,29.874,23,29.883z M20,12H4v2h16V12z" style="/* transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); *//* stroke: black; */"/>
        <g>
            <polygon points="28,22 24.002,22 24.002,18 22,18 22,22 18,22 18,24 22,24 22,28 24.002,28 24.002,24 28,24   "/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Is there any online editor which can do that? Or maybe there is some css tricks that I don't know?

Comment: Load it in inkscape and adjust the shape

Comment: Do it the stupid way: add `path, polygon{stroke-width:1px;stroke:white;}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Path thickness is negligible. Your path is not defining the lines you see, it is defining the *border* of those lines explicitly. You can see what the path describes by adding `stroke="red"`. You can't decrease the thickness of the filled-in polygons by fiddling with the attributes alone. The only thing you *can* do without completely redoing the path is to use the background-colour stroke to erase part of the filled-in portion, though I'd argue it can't look as good as a hand-crafted icon:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <g>
        <path stroke-width="1" stroke="white" d="M24,14.059V5.584L18.414,0H0v32h24v-0.059c4.499-0.5,7.998-4.309,8-8.941C31.998,18.366,28.499,14.556,24,14.059z    M17.998,2.413L21.586,6h-3.588V2.413z M2,30V1.998h14v6.001h6v6.06c-1.752,0.194-3.352,0.89-4.652,1.941H4v2h11.517   c-0.412,0.616-0.743,1.289-0.994,2H4v2h10.059C14.022,22.329,14,22.661,14,23c0,2.829,1.308,5.351,3.349,7H2z M23,29.883   c-3.801-0.009-6.876-3.084-6.885-6.883c0.009-3.801,3.084-6.876,6.885-6.885c3.799,0.009,6.874,3.084,6.883,6.885   C29.874,26.799,26.799,29.874,23,29.883z M20,12H4v2h16V12z" style="/* transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); *//* stroke: black; */"/>
        <g>
            <polygon stroke-width="1" stroke="white" points="28,22 24.002,22 24.002,18 22,18 22,22 18,22 18,24 22,24 22,28 24.002,28 24.002,24 28,24   "/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great solution @Amadan. I used it with a stroke width of 14 to trim down a really clunky icon to something much more elegant.